# Decrease Matlab for loop

Tags: matlab

```
% read image
I = imread(im);
H = zeros(256,1);
% m = width, n = height
[m,n] = size(I);

% loop for checking values
for GrayValue = 0:255
    for i = 1:m
        for j = 1:n
            if I(i,j) == GrayValue % read each pixel coordinate
                H(GrayValue+1) = H(GrayValue+1)+1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This function it go get image file as `im` and will show a histogram of values count in the image. How can i reduce the time taken to execute this MATLAB function. It is similar to `imhist()` . But I want to make a similar `imhist()` function. I cannot figure out to remove which loop.

Comment: So you do not want to use `imhist()` nor `hist()` or `histc()` right?

Comment: Yes... I do not want to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory `bsxfun` solution:

```
H=sum(bsxfun(@eq,I(:),0:255))
```

And a method that might be easier to understand. This just replaces your two inner loops with a search.

```
I=randi(256,50,50)-1;
H=zeros(256,1);

G=zeros(256,1);
for GrayValue=0:255
    [ii,jj]=find(I==GrayValue);
    G(GrayValue+1)=length(ii);
end
```

Comment: Which line should I put this?

Comment: This works for me. Do you have a solution where use of the code I implement to check each coordinate? a more less advanced code :P

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris I've edited my answer to include a different method. It should be easier to understand, but try to understand both if you are trying to learn Matlab. `bsxfun` (as well as `cellfun`) can be very useful tools once you learn how they work (I'm still learning!). Be sure to read the documentation for the functions carefully to help work out what they really do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `I` to be a grayscale image, you can use **[`histc`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/histc.html)** to get `H` -

```
H = sum(histc(I,0:255),2)
```

Thus, the complete code would be -

```
% read image
I = imread(im);
H = sum(histc(I,0:255),2)
```

---

If you were looking for a little less-advanced code, you can avoid one nested loop -

```
% read image
I = imread(im);
H = zeros(256,1);

% loop for checking values
for GrayValue = 0:255
    for i = 1:numel(I)
        if I(i) == GrayValue % read each pixel coordinate
            H(GrayValue+1) = H(GrayValue+1)+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: where should I put this function?

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris You were looking to get `H` without using loops, right?

Comment: yah. How should i do it?

Comment: I am using loops.. but I do not want to use the existing function. like histc();

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris same as with david's solution. Just put it below the imread comand.

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris Why do you not want to use `histc`? Could you clarify on that?

Comment: I do not want to use existing function like histc(); @Divakar

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris Fair enough then. David's solution uses `bsxfun`, which doesn't need any toolbox, so I guess that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Divakar I will try to understand your code to make it works. I am in the process of learning, things are still  new for me, so I wouldn't just jump to use exist code directly. Why not study how they make the code. :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: @SanbronsLycoris Those restrictions! Just pegs you back! Well I have added a little less-advanced loop code, if that seems not-so-complicated? Personally, I would encourage you to read up on `bsxfun`, as it's a wonderful tool!